# Передача файла на сервер

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Нашёл на stackoverflow тему как передавать файл с клиента на сервер.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204621/send-image-to-server-using-file-input-type
Попробовал сделать то же самое, но что то не получается.
Вот мой код:

```
<input id="fileLoader" type="file" />
```

JS:

```
//Добавление нового автомобиля
    $('#modalWindow').on('click', '#btnConfirm', function () {

        var file = $('#fileLoader')[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("sendFile", file);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/_AddNewCar",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

На контроллере делаю тип принимаемых данных, object.
Во первых в различаи от примера, пришлось изменить строчку `var file = $('#fileLoader')[0].files[0];`, в теме которую я для примера привёл она выглядит так `var file = $('#fileLoader').files[0];` но так вылетает ошибка, а как я написал файл выбирается. Но почему то вылетает ошибка на строчке

```
data: formData,
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно нужно как нибудь по другому передавать? Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Как можно передать файл на сервер?

Код моего контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _AddNewCar(Object file)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Comment: Если копируете код, копируйте его правильно! Вы забыли добавить параметры 
       `processData: false,`
       `contentType: false,`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, дай действительно, теперь передалось. Только передалось что то странное. На сервер пришла object перемення с содержанием `{object}`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko как я предполога, придёт файл. А там пустота по сути.

Comment: Вы лучше смотрите в DevTools во влкадке Network, что отправляется. Отправляется файл. А как его считать - ищите, как на C# считывать данные `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вот что отправляется `sendFile: (binary)`

Comment: Ну значит все верно, файл отправляется. Осталось его только правильно принять. Например вот здесь куча вариантов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post. Какой выбрать - зависит от того, что вы используете на сервере.